# Django Rest - get related data in M2M relation

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have 2 models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    music_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    date = models.DateField()
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

For every artist I would like to get list of other artists if they have ever been in any event together.

I was able to create close solution, but only for specific artist:

```
def get_related_artists(request):

    artist_id = 2
    related_events = Artist.objects.filter(id=artist_id).first().event_set.all()
    related_artists_ids = []
    for event in related_events:
        related_artists_ids = related_artists_ids + list(event.artists
                                                     .all()
                                                     .values_list('id', flat=True)
                                                     .all())
    related_artists = Artist.objects\
    .filter(id__in=set(related_artists_ids))\
    .exclude(id=artist_id)

    serializer = ArtistRelatedSerializer(related_artists, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

So firstly I get all event where specific artist took part. Later I iterate over this events and get other artist's ids. Another step is to remove duplicated ids and specific artist id. At the end I use serializer to return data.

Serializer looks like:

```
class ArtistRelatedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = '__all__'
```

Unfortunately I think it isn't optimal solution and works only for hardcoded artist's id. I would like to get all artists and for ech list of other artists.
I was thinking about creating loop and iterate over `Artist.objects.count()` but I couldn't find a solid solution to maintain all this queries.

Is there any other, maybe easier way to solve this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue from Serializer by using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Get all events in each Artist, the example below:

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'music_type', 'events')

    events = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_events(self, obj):
        events_qs = Event.objects.filter(artists__in=[obj.id])
        events = EventSerializer(
            events_qs, many=True, context=self.context).data
        return events
```

To avoid the error by the circle imports, you should use `import` in the function